# Why are the sizes of these mnesia tables appear different on different nodes?

Tags: erlang, elixir, mnesia

So running mnesia in a multi-node (2 node) cluster with disc_copies as an option, when I log onto the server and inspect the directory contents with `ls -l`, I see the following mnesia table sizes:

Node 1:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8 Jul 25 20:58 applications.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1530 Jul 26 00:25 applications.DCL
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    132 Jul 26 01:10 LATEST.LOG
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8 Jul 25 20:58 table.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 237451 Jul 26 00:43 table.DCL
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      8 Jul 25 20:58 kite_table.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  80707 Jul 26 00:43 kite_table.DCL
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14730 Jul 26 01:03 schema.DAT
```

Node 2:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    196 Jul 26 01:13 DECISION_TAB.LOG
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1238 Jul 26 01:10 applications.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    132 Jul 26 01:13 LATEST.LOG
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 233483 Jul 26 01:10 table.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  80674 Jul 26 01:10 kite_table.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17032 Jul 26 01:09 schema.DAT
```

But extracting the same data with a call to `:mnesia.info()`, I see:

Node 1:

```
table         : with 64       records occupying 38477    words of mem
kite_table    : with 1        records occupying 13562    words of mem
applications: with 4        records occupying 488      words of mem
schema         : with 9        records occupying 1486     words of mem
```

Node 2:

```
table         : with 64       records occupying 38477    words of mem
kite_table    : with 1        records occupying 13562    words of mem
applications: with 4        records occupying 488      words of mem
schema         : with 9        records occupying 1486     words of mem
```

Then it appears the data is the same size and consistent.  Can anyone explain the apparent inconsistency?

The code below shows a typical call done in the system for :mnesia.create_table/2

```
opts = [
  {:attributes, [id: nil, data: %{}]},
  {:type, :set},
  {:index, []},
  {:disc_copies, [node() | Node.list([:visible])]}
]

:mnesia.create_table(:kite_table, opts)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that creates database.
Arguments of function  mnesia:create_table will be helpful.

Comment: Updated @YuriGinsburg with typical call to create_table/2, thanks

Comment: I started two nodes on my computer, then used `{disc_copies, [n1@mymbp2, n2@mymbp2]}` in the `mnesia:create_table()` function, and I'm seeing the same thing as you.

Answer (score 1):

My reading of the [erlang mnesia docs](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap7.html#log-file) indicates that that may be a normal occurrence:

> When starting Mnesia, a .LOG file called LATEST.LOG is created and
>   placed in the database directory. This file is used by Mnesia to log
>   disc-based transactions. This includes all transactions that write at
>   least one record in a table that is of storage type disc_copies or
>   disc_only_copies. The file also includes all operations that
>   manipulate the schema itself, such as creating new tables. The log
>   format can vary with different implementations of Mnesia. The Mnesia
>   log is currently implemented in the standard library module disk_log
>   in Kernel.
>
> The log file grows continuously and must be dumped at regular
>   intervals. "Dumping the log file" means that Mnesia performs all the
>   operations listed in the log and place the records in the
>   corresponding .DAT, .DCD, and .DCL data files. For example, if the
>   operation "write record {foo, 4, elvis, 6}" is listed in the log,
>   Mnesia inserts the operation into the file foo.DCL. Later, when Mnesia
>   thinks that the .DCL file is too large, the data is moved to the .DCD
>   file. The dumping operation can be time consuming if the log is large.
>   Notice that the Mnesia system continues to operate during log dumps.
>
> By default Mnesia either dumps the log whenever 100 records have been
>   written in the log or when three minutes have passed. This is
>   controlled by the two application parameters -mnesia
>   dump_log_write_threshold WriteOperations and -mnesia
>   dump_log_time_threshold MilliSecs.

I do wish the docs for `info()` said something like:

> Retrieves the table information from the RAM copies of the table.

The docs also say:

> **disc_copies.** This property specifies a list of Erlang nodes where the table is kept in RAM and on disc. All updates of the table are
>   performed in the actual table and are also logged to disc....Each
>   transaction performed on the table is appended to a LOG file and
>   written into the RAM table.

What do the file sizes look like after you shut down your application?  I would expect them to be equivalent.

Comment: thanks @7stud, a lot of the file sizes between the 2 nodes are different. Even LATEST.LOG is 232 on one node and 132 on the other node.